# How to find login and password input in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to find login and password input in Selenium WebDriver?

I tryed with .//*[@id='login_input'] and .//*[@id='password'] but is one problem: these fields input are loaded by script JavaScript. Source code page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="http://oexchange.org/spec/0.8/rel/related-target" type="application/xrd+xml" href="http://www.gg.pl/info/static/files/oexchange.xrd"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/info/1.2.0/css/style.css" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="/info/1.2.0/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <title>GG - pobierz najpopularniejszy polski komunikator</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="gg, gadu, gadu-gadu, komunikator, gg download, gg pobierz, web gadu, mobilne gg, gg android, gg iphone, gg linux, gg windows, gg na telefon, gg w przeglądarce, webowe gg, przesyłanie plików, katalog publiczny, archiwum gg">
        <meta name="description" content="Pobierz komunikator GG dostępny na systemy Windows, OS X, Linux, na telefony komórkowe: iPhone oraz z systemem Android, Windows Phone i inne. Korzystaj z GG także przez stronę WWW.">
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.gg.pl/" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="GG - pobierz najpopularniejszy polski komunikator" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="GG" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Pobierz komunikator GG dostępny na systemy Windows, OS X, Linux, na telefony komórkowe: iPhone oraz z systemem Android, Windows Phone i inne. Korzystaj z GG także przez stronę WWW." />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.gg.pl/info/1.2.0/img/scfbg.png" />
        <meta property="og:locale" content="pl_PL" />
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="d109cRFzSCCNSp1FE0PJ1u8iyomEuC7fG0Hi1J-xMh4" />
        <script> if(self != top){ top.location = self.location; }</script>                <script>
        var clientId = "13a8aec5f6e60b5880d83fdd18a314d5";
        var App = function () {

    var showLoginForm = function showLoginForm() {
        gg.Connect.Internal.embeddedLogin({
            'container': 'login-form-container',
            'attributes': {
                'class': 'com frame centered',
                'height': '522px',
                'width': '290px',
                'frameBorder': 0,
                'allowtransparency': "true",
                'scrolling': 'no'
            }
        });
    };

    var embeddedLogout = function embeddedLogout() {
        gg.Connect.Internal.embeddedLogout({
            'attributes': {
                'width': '1px',
                'height': '1px',
                'frameBorder': 0
            }
        }, loginCallback, logoutCallback);
    };

    var startApp = function start() {
        onLoginHandler();
    }

    var shutdownApp = function shutdown() {
    }

    var onLoginHandler = function onLoginHandler(event) {
        var hash = encodeURIComponent(window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
        document.location = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + document.location.host + '/authorize/login?redirect=' + hash;
    }

    var onLogoutHandler = function onLogoutHandler(event) {
        window.location.href = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + document.location.host + '/logout';
    }

    var onSessionChangeHandler = function onSessionChangeHandler(event) {
    }

    var onStatusChangeHandler = function onStatusChangeHandler(event) {
        if (event.data && event.data.isLogged()) {
            startApp();
        }
    }

    return {
        showLoginForm: showLoginForm,
        onLoginHandler: onLoginHandler,
        onLogoutHandler: onLogoutHandler,
        onSessionChangeHandler: onSessionChangeHandler,
        onStatusChangeHandler: onStatusChangeHandler
    }
}

var app = new App();

window.ggReady = function () {
    gg.Events.hook("auth.login", function onLoginHandler(event) {
        app.onLoginHandler(event);
    });

    gg.Events.hook("auth.logout", function onLogoutHandler(event) {
        app.onLogoutHandler(event);
    });

    gg.Events.hook("auth.session_change", function onSessionChangeHandler(event) {
        app.onSessionChangeHandler(event);
    });

    gg.Events.hook("status.change", function onStatusChangeHandler(event) {
        app.onStatusChangeHandler(event);
    });

    gg.initialize({
        "client_id": clientId,
        "urlhashUri": "info/transport.html"
    });
}
        </script>
        <!-- (C)2000-2012 Gemius SA - gemiusTraffic / ver 11.1 / info/sg -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--

            var pp_gemius_identifier = 'ciTqKINTm7f7okmGLy_rpnXpXtcZVmOgwVLZnWQiDgz.s7';
            // lines below shouldn't be edited
            function gemius_pending(i) { window[i] = window[i] || function() {var x = window[i+'_pdata'] = window[i+'_pdata']
                    || []; x[x.length]=arguments;};};
            gemius_pending('gemius_hit'); gemius_pending('gemius_event'); gemius_pending('pp_gemius_hit');
            gemius_pending('pp_gemius_event');
            //--><!]]>
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://login.gg.pl/js/libs/0.9.5/igg.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <div>
        <div id="content" class="container">

            <header>
            <div id="logo-container" class="row scheduler-jesien">
    <div class="span5 offset1" id="logo">
        <h1><img src="/info/1.2.0/img/glowna_logo.png" alt="GG - pobierz najpopularniejszy polski komunikator" title="GG - pobierz najpopularniejszy polski komunikator" />
        <span class="smaller polski">Polski.</span>
        <span class="smaller najpopularniejszy">Najpopularniejszy.</span>
        <span class="komunikator" >Komunikator.</span></h1>
        <a title="Pobierz GG" class="btn btn-larger btn-primary" href="/info/pobierz/?start=1">Pobierz GG</a>    </div>
    <div class="span5 offset1" id="login-form-container" style="background-color: transparent;"></div>
</div><nav class="main-navigation yellow">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav desktop-clients">
                <li class="first"><a title="GG na Windows" href="/info/pobierz/?start=windows">Windows</a></li>
                <li><a title="GG na Apple OSX" href="/info/pobierz/?start=mac">OS X</a></li>
                <li><a title="GG na Linux" href="/info/pobierz/?start=linux">Linux</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a title="GG na Windows 8" href="http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/pl-pl/app/gg/5268c140-3e81-41e4-8cef-6ac5b3399526">Windows 8</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav mobile-clients">
                <li class="first"><a title="GG na Android" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.gadugadu">Android</a></li>
                <li><a title="GG na iPhone" href="http://itunes.apple.com/pl/app/gadu-gadu/id308095268">iPhone</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a title="GG na Windows Phone" href="http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=81fa3f08-d030-42ba-b36c-37b95908b6d7">Windows Phone</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
            </header>

            <div id="main">

<div class="section yellow text-center">
    <h2><a title="W domu, w pracy, w drodze" href="http://www.gg.pl/info/na-komputer-przegladarke-telefon/">W domu, w pracy, w drodze</a></h2>
    <p>Rozmawiaj na komputerze i komórce.</p>
    <p>Możesz też rozmawiać w przeglądarce bez instalowania komunikatora.</p>

    <a title="W domu, w pracy, w drodze" href="http://www.gg.pl/info/na-komputer-przegladarke-telefon/" class="arrow"></a>
</div>

<div class="bg-chat-windows">
       <img title="Rozmawiaj na komputerze i komórce." alt="Rozmawiaj na komputerze i komórce." src="/info/1.2.0/img/bg_chat_windows.png" />
</div>

<div class="section blue text-center">

    <h2><a title="Bezpieczne rozmowy" href="http://www.gg.pl/info/bezpieczny-komunikator/">Bezpieczne rozmowy</a></h2>
    <p>Korzystając z oficjalnej wersji komunikatora GG możesz czuć
        <br />się bezpiecznie. Rozmowy, które prowadzisz są szyfrowane
        <br />i zapisywane* w archiwum on-line, abyś nigdy ich nie stracił.</p>

    <a title="Bezpieczne rozmowy" href="http://www.gg.pl/info/bezpieczny-komunikator/" class="arrow"></a>

    <div id="gg_promo_avatar" class="avatar"></div>
    <p class="star"><span>*</span>Szanujemy Twoją prywatność, więc masz pełną kontrolę nad tym co trafi do archiwum.</p>
</div>

<div class="section yellow-two text-center">
    <h2>Konferencje z przyjaciółmi</h2>
    <p>Rozmawiaj z grupą znajomych w jednym oknie.</p>
    <p>Do każdej rozmowy możesz dodać więcej osób.</p>

    <img title="Konferencje z przyjaciółmi" alt="Konferencje z przyjaciółmi" src="/info/1.2.0/img/bg_section_yellow_two.png" />
</div>

<div class="section home-plugin text-center">
    <h2><a href="/info/gg-plugin/" title="GG Plugin">GG Plugin</a></h2>
    <p>Nie przegap żadnej wiadomości od znajomych.</p>
    <a title="GG Plugin - wtyczka dla Chrome" href="/info/gg-plugin/" class="arrow"></a>
    <img title="GG Plugin - wtyczka dla Chrome" alt="GG Plugin - wtyczka dla Chrome" src="/info/1.2.0/img/bg_home_plugin.png" />
</div>

<div class="section home-ggwidget text-center">
    <h2><a title="GG widżet - komunikator na Twoją stronę" href="http://www.gg.pl/info/komunikator-na-twoja-strone/">GG widżet - komunikator na Twoją stronę</a></h2>
    <p>Darmowe narzędzie<br/>do szybkiej i niezawodnej komunikacji online z Twoimi klientami.</p>

    <a title="GG widżet - komunikator na Twoją stronę" href="http://www.gg.pl/info/komunikator-na-twoja-strone/" class="arrow"></a>
    <p>
        <a title="GG widżet, komunikator na Twoją stronę" href="http://www.gg.pl/info/komunikator-na-twoja-strone/">
            <img title="GG widżet" alt="GG widżet" src="/info/1.2.0/img/gg-widget.png" />
        </a>
    </p>

</div>

<div class="section rainbow text-center">
    <h2>Poznaj nowych znajomych.<br>Wtedy, kiedy chcesz. Tam, gdzie jesteś.</h2>
    <p>Wystarczy kilka sekund, aby trafić na osobę, która chce Cię poznać.<br>Takich osób są miliony. Może to być ktoś z Twojej miejscowości<br>lub oddalony o wiele kilometrów. Klika w przycisk "Losuj rozmówcę".<br>Ty robisz to samo i gotowe. Trafiacie na siebie.<br>To może być początek ciekawej znajomości albo czegoś więcej...</p>
    <a title="Dla tych co lubią poznawać" href="/losuj/" class="arrow"></a>
    <div><img class="losuj-faces" src="/info/1.2.0/img/losuj-faces-front.png" alt="Dla tych co lubią poznawać" title="Dla tych co lubią poznawać"></div>
</div>
            </div>


            <footer class="text-center">
                                <ul class="inline">
                      <li><a title="Pobierz GG" href="http://www.gg.pl/info/pobierz/">Pobierz GG</a></li>
                      <li><a title="Pomoc" href="http://www.gg.pl/pomoc/">Pomoc</a></li>
                      <li><a title="Regulamin" href="http://www.gg.pl/prawne/regulamin/">Regulamin</a></li>
                      <li><a title="Prywatność" href="http://www.gg.pl/prawne/polityka-prywatnosci/">Prywatność</a></li>
                      <li><a title="Zgłoś nadużycie" href="http://www.gg.pl/kontakt">Zgłoś nadużycie</a></li>
                      <li><a title="Reklama" href="http://reklama-w.gg.pl">Reklama</a></li>
                      <li><a title="Kontakt" href="http://www.gg.pl/kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>&copy; 2017 Xevin Consulting Limited</p>
                        </footer>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
                <script>
        try{(function(){function g(a){for(var b=0,c=0;a;)b+=a.offsetLeft-a.scrollLeft+a.clientLeft,c+=a.offsetTop-a.scrollTop+a.clientTop,a=a.offsetParent;return{x:b,y:c}}function k(a,b,c){if(80>b)return 4;if(0<=a.x&&0<=a.y)return 5>c?7:67<c?5:8;if(0<=a.x&&0>a.y)return-23<c?1:-67>c?5:2;if(0>a.x&&0>a.y)return 5>c?1:50<c?3:0;if(0>a.x&&0<=a.y)return-45<c?7:-70>c?3:6}function h(a,b,c){b.addEventListener?b.addEventListener(a,c,!1):b.attachEvent&&b.attachEvent("on"+a,c)}var l="0px 0px;-203px 0px;-411px 0px;0px -183px;-203px -183px;-411px -183px;0px -365px;-203px -365px;-411px -365px".split(";"),
d={x:0,y:0},e=document.getElementById("gg_promo_avatar"),f=g(e);h("mousemove",document,function(a){try{var b={x:a.pageX-f.x-75,y:a.pageY-f.y-75};20>Math.abs(d.x-b.x)+Math.abs(d.y-b.y)||(d=b,e.style.backgroundPosition=l[k(b,Math.sqrt(b.x*b.x+b.y*b.y),180/Math.PI*Math.atan(b.x/b.y))])}catch(c){}});h("resize",window,function(){try{f=g(e)}catch(a){}})})()}catch(m){};
    app.showLoginForm();
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/info/1.2.0/js/cookie-terms.min.js"></script>
                <!-- (C)2000-2012 Gemius SA - gemiusTraffic / ver 11.1 / info/sg -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--

            function appendGemius() {
                (function(d,t) {var ex; try {var
                        gt=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],l='http'+((location.protocol=='https:')?'s':'');
                    gt.async='true'; gt.src=l+'://gg.hit.gemius.pl/xgemius.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gt,s);} catch (ex)
                {}})(document,'script');
            }

            if (window.addEventListener) {
                window.addEventListener("load", appendGemius, false);
            }
            else if (window.attachEvent) {
                window.attachEvent("onload", appendGemius);
            }
            //--><!]]>
        </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-25319304-4']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/login-page']);
            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
        </script>
                    <!-- BUILD VERSION: 1.2.0 -->
            </body>
</html>
```

This is the script: XPATH: html/body/script[1]
The source code script:

```
<script>   try{(function(){function g(a){for(var b=0,c=0;a;)b+=a.offsetLeft-a.scrollLeft+a.clientLeft,c+=a.offsetTop-a.scrollTop+a.clientTop,a=a.offsetParent;return{x:b,y:c}}function k(a,b,c){if(80>b)return 4;if(0<=a.x&&0<=a.y)return 5>c?7:67<c?5:8;if(0<=a.x&&0>a.y)return-23<c?1:-67>c?5:2;if(0>a.x&&0>a.y)return 5>c?1:50<c?3:0;if(0>a.x&&0<=a.y)return-45<c?7:-70>c?3:6}function h(a,b,c){b.addEventListener?b.addEventListener(a,c,!1):b.attachEvent&&b.attachEvent("on"+a,c)}var l="0px 0px;-203px 0px;-411px 0px;0px -183px;-203px -183px;-411px -183px;0px -365px;-203px -365px;-411px -365px".split(";"), d={x:0,y:0},e=document.getElementById("gg_promo_avatar"),f=g(e);h("mousemove",document,function(a){try{var b={x:a.pageX-f.x-75,y:a.pageY-f.y-75};20>Math.abs(d.x-b.x)+Math.abs(d.y-b.y)||(d=b,e.style.backgroundPosition=l[k(b,Math.sqrt(b.x*b.x+b.y*b.y),180/Math.PI*Math.atan(b.x/b.y))])}catch(c){}});h("resize",window,function(){try{f=g(e)}catch(a){}})})()}catch(m){}; app.showLoginForm(); </script>
```

How I can run this script that adds form login? I don't have any idea. You can find this page at the address https://www.gg.pl/ (if it's against the law please remove the address). Thank you very much for help!

Comment: I suggest you load the web page in a web browser. Then right click on the element and select Inspect from the menu. Now you can look at the generated tags and determine what attributes can be used to select the element in Selenium.

Comment: Please retry, but click on the another place than form - //input[@id='login_input'] and //input[@id='password'] is not presence on the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nifty one. Seems like the page doesn't want you to scrape it ;-) The page wraps the login form into an `iframe` so you have to find out this `iframe` first and switch to it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import by
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui, expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.gg.pl/')

iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="com frame centered"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
element_login = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by.By.ID, 'login_input')))
element_password = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by.By.ID, 'password')))
# or use xpath if you like:
#element_login = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by.By.XPATH, '//input[@id="login_input"]')))
#element_password = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by.By.XPATH, '//input[@id="password"]')))
```

Also, note that I used implicit waiting so selenium will wait 10 seconds max. for the login input to appear on page (and be accessible). This technique will protect you against long page loads where `driver.find_element_by...` can fail if the page is not being loaded fast enough.

Comment: Super! Work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are waiting long enough for the Javascript to execute. You should take a screen shot of the web page before you try to set the login. (That would tell you if you have waited long enough, and if the fields have loaded.)

Comment: I'm waiting enough and the program take screenshot. In the picture is login form, but .//[@id='login_input'] and .//[@id='password'] is not loaded. Maybe Selenium can find input without attributes?